# Add maven capability to Team Services build agent

Tags: maven, service, tfs, build, agent

What's the correct way to setup maven on a Team Services Default build agent?

What I have done so far:

- I have downloaded the agent on a virtual machine
- I have manually installed java and maven on that machine (C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_101 resp C:\Java\maven\apache-maven-3.3.9)
- I have added a few environment variables (maven, MAVEN_HOME, M2_HOME)
- after that I install the agent using the powershel script .\config.cmd

The agent gets succesfully registered in my visualstudio.com environment, but the maven capability does not get picked up:

[image: No maven capability]

After reading several other posts, I manually added the "maven" capability to the agent:

[image: manually added maven capability]

After all this I can start a build that requires maven. But unfortunately the build fails:

[image: Build fails]

How do I get maven to work properly on my default build agent? I cannot find a solution in the MS documentation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To answer my own question. The mistake that I made was that I created the environment variables as user variables instead of system variables. To sum things up, here's what's needed:

- download the agent on a virtual machine
- installed java and maven on that machine
- add SYSTEM environment variables M2_HOME and JAVA_HOME
- install the agent using the powershel script .\config.cmd

Comment: great, thank you so much for what you shared here. Did you ever run into "compilation error" issues with the very maven projects?

Comment: we had some misconfigurations in the test project, but the One Additional thing that we had to install on the build server was an appropriate BROWSER (Chrome in our case). And just to make things more specific, I personally set the M2_HOME to the maven root installation directory (not the bin), Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

1. Download the agent on a virtual machine
2. Install java and maven on that machine add SYSTEM environment variables M2_HOME and JAVA_HOME
3. Run 'path' in command prompt and ensure that the maven installation directory is listed.
4. Ensure the maven is installed in 'C:\Program Files\Maven'.
5. Install the agent using the powershel script .\config.cmd.
6. Restart server or Update agent from Devops Portal.

In my case I have installed in C drive on root and getting error.